# Oracleのexpコマンドで直接SCPなどでリモートホストのディスクにダンプしたい

Tags: ssh, oracle, scp

お世話になります。
Oracleの11gを利用しております。localホストのHDDの容量が枯渇し、すべてのデータをダンプできない状態なのですが、expコマンドにて直接scpなどで転送できるコマンドはないでしょうか？

> exp USER/PASSWORD file=/tmp/expdat.dmp owner=USER

という標準のコマンドで、`file=/tmp/expdat.dmp`の部分を別のホストに転送できる方法がないか模索中です。nasのマウントなど、諸事情によりできない状態で、現行で接続できるプロトコルがsshのみとなっております。`//192.168.0.2:/tmp/expdat.dmp`のような書き方でダンプファイルを直接リモートホストへ転送できないか？という感じです。

詳しい方いましたら、ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: リモートに送りつける発想と思いますが、sshfsでリモートのディレクトリをマウントする発想はアリですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。当初できないという話だったのですが、500GBマウントするかたちでテストさせてもらいました。その方法ですと当然問題なく動作しました。今回はnfsマウントしました。やはり直接転送するようなCommandは今のところなさそうな気がしております。